# Windows command line access denied to install service, and I'm the administrator

Tags: windows, winapi, python-3.x

I'm attempting to install a windows service with Python (3.4). Upon installation I intend to run it. It doesn't perform any function other than demo a service running in Windows.

I'm getting the following access permission when installing the service:

[image]

I'm the admin for the computer therefore I should have the permission to do this.

Perhaps its because the command line is attempting install the service with a Python. Does Python have permission to do this through the command line?

How can I get past this issue. Is there a specific file with permissions that I need to change?

I've included the code from the service just in case.

The help is appreciated.

```
#Run a Windows Service

import win32serviceutil
import win32service
import win32event
import os
import sys
import time
from threading import Thread
import http.server

class ServiceLauncher(win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework):
    _svc_name_ = "PythonService"
    _svc_display_name_ = "Python based win32 service"
    _svc_description_ = ""

def __init__(self, args):
    win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework.__init__(self, args)
    self.hWaitStop = win32event.CreateEvent(None, 0, 0, None)

def SvcStop(self):
    self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOP_PENDING)
    win32event.SetEvent(self.hWaitStop)

def SvcDoRun(self):
    thread = Thread(target = httpserver.run_httpserver)
    thread.daemon = True
    thread.start()

    while (1):
        rc = win32event.WaitForSingleObject(self.hWaitStop, 1000)
        if rc==win32event.WAIT_OBJECT_0:
            # Stop event
            break

if __name__ == '__main__':
    win32serviceutil.HandleCommandLine(ServiceLauncher)
```

Comment: User Account Control (UAC) might get in the way: Did you explictly start the command line with administrative privileges? (If so, it should say "Administrator" somewhere in the command line window's title bar.)

Comment: You probably aren't admin. You probably are standard user with the UAC split token.

Answer (score 0):

The solution involves running the command line as an administrator. This is performed by right clicking the command prompt and selecting to run the command line as an administrator.

In Windows, the user logged into the computer may be a Windows administrator but the rights do not automatically extend to the command line. The user with administrator rights has to choose to run the command line as an administrator in order to perform the commands reserved to administrators such as performing an install of a Windows service.